# i need to have a list of icons tha can be changed by swipping and by doing so the whole content changes

Tags: java, android

thanks for the help in advance, what i wanna achieve is a list of icons that need to be changed by swipping left and right when i change them i need the whole content too change li the exemple bellow:

[see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKGbb.jpg)

i only create a small amoubt of the like linear behind the icon and the icon and the title.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/aboutback"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picM"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logowhite"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="title"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: like this? https://github.com/GoodieBag/CarouselPicker

Comment: Exactly if you would add it as an answer it would be better, and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a library that exist already. You can always fork it if its not quite perfect for your implementation.

https://github.com/GoodieBag/CarouselPicker

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a RecyclerView with a horizontal orientation.

It is a very simple implementation, you could read the official Android guide:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Regards!